# The Tutte Polynomial - is a `crossing' the same as a `bridge'?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, tutte-polynomial

Hey guys,

The following paper uses the term `bridge' in their definition of the Tutte polynomial:

Bennett Thompson, David J. Pearce, Craig Anslow, and Gary Haggard. Visualizing the computation tree of the tutte polynomial. In Proceedings of the 4th ACM sympo- sium on Software visualization, SoftVis ’08, pages 211–212, New York, NY, USA, 2008. ACM. Available from: http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1409720.1409760, doi:http: //doi.acm.org/10.1145/1409720.1409760.

However, the Wiki page and other papers use the term `crossing'.

Are these the same thing or am I confusing them?  What do you think?

Thank you.

Comment: Since the cited paper is behind a paywall it would be helpful if you reproduced the definition you want explained in your question.

Comment: @AaronDall I had a look at the paper and the definition given is: "a
bridge is an edge whose removal disconnects two or more vertices (i.e. there is no longer a path between them)." It also looks like this link http://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~djp/files/TPH-SIENZ07.pdf leads to a slightly expanded version of the paper.

Comment: Thanks for the look-up @j.c. That's the definition used below in both Greg Kuperberg's answer and in mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wikipedia page for the [Tutte polynmomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial) doesn't use the word crossing, it also uses the word bridge.  In graph theory, a bridge of a connected graph is an edge that separates the graph into two components.

However, there is a relation between the Tutte polynomial and the Jones and HOMFLY polynomials.  More precisely, the HOMFLY polynomial [generalizes the Tutte polynomial for planar graph](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2047194).  A knot diagram has crossings, which means points where two arcs of the knot cross.  A knot diagram also has bridges; a bridge is a maximal sequence of over-crossings along an arc of the diagram.  So there is a little bit of collision of terminology, because crossings aren't bridges and because bridges for knots aren't the same as bridges for graphs.

Comment: And of course Tutte used "bridge" with a completely different meaning.
The joys of terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to the cited paper but if the term [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)) is used as in the answer of @Greg Kuperberg (**edit:** and it is) then other synonyms from graph theory are **isthmus**, **cut-edge**, and **cut-arc**. An important feature of such a bridge $e$ of a (possibly disconnected) graph $G$ is that if $F$ is any spanning forest of $G$, then $e$ must be an edge in $F$. Equivalently, $e$ is not contained in any cycle of $G$. If $G$ is planar then the dual edge $e^*$ in the dual graph $G^*$ is a loop (a cycle of length one).

More generally, one can study the [Tutte polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Tutte_polynomial) of a matroid. In this context an element $e$ that is in every basis of a given matroid is called an **isthmus** or a **coloop**.